# Userscripts in Chrome Apps

Tags: google-chrome, userscripts

Is there a way to run a userscipt on a Chrome App? I have tried using something like:

```
// @include        chrome-extension://lhdicadblnoidhgkllhdgkagmflbmbcn/*
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `// @include *` doesn't work?   Is it a *Packaged App*?  If so, then you can probably adapt its manifest file to run your userscript/content-script.

Comment: `*` doesn't work. Not sure what a packaged app is (got it from the web store). And if the only solution is to alter the app itself, I could as well skip the userscipt altogether.

Comment: Just for giggles, what is the app?  Might take a look while I'm stuck here on holiday (no promises).

Comment: Not that important, really, a Twitter client called Kwitty (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lhdicadblnoidhgkllhdgkagmflbmbcn?hl=en-US). I just wanted to get rid of the horrible Trebuchet font.

Comment: If you just want to change the font (or any other CSS styles), then [Stylish](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe) might work for you.

Comment: Nope, that too doesn't seem to work on apps. But thanks for the suggestion, it might be useful elsewhere.